# Scrape webpage with dynamic javascript using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web page with dynamic javascript loading using selenium, but the table that I want to scrape is never actually loading in the source and is instead just showing javascript. The code I am trying to run is the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ""

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/Users/brendanbernstein/Downloads/geckodriver')
browser.get(url)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "maintable")))

html_page = browser.page_source
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
```

Unfortunately, even using selenium, the javascript is not executing. The script that executes and generates the table I believe looks like the below and is all I'm seeing in the scraped source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (hash != '') {
            activaTab(hash);
        } else {
            loadIframeSource3();
        };
        //$('i').tooltip({ placement: 'bottom', trigger: 'manual' }).tooltip('show');
    });
    function activaTab(tab) {
        if (tab.indexOf('comment') >= 0) {
            tab = 'comments';
            loaddisqus();
        } else if (tab.indexOf('readContract') >= 0) {
            loadIframeSource();
        } else if (tab.indexOf('balances') >= 0) {
            loadIframeSource2();
        };
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
    };
    function updatehash(strhash) {
        if (strhash == '') {
            history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
        } else {
            var baseUrl = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
            history.replaceState("", document.title, baseUrl + '#' + strhash);
        }
    }

    var disqusloaded = false;
    function loaddisqus() {
        if (disqusloaded == false) {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
            disqusloaded = true;
        }
        updatehash('comments');
    }

    var readContractLoaded = false;
    function loadIframeSource() {
        if (readContractLoaded == false) {
            readContractLoaded = true;
            document.getElementById('readcontractiframe').src = '/readContract?a=0xe94327d07fc17907b4db788e5adf2ed424addff6&v=0xe94327d07fc17907b4db788e5adf2ed424addff6';
        }
    }
    var token_holders_loaded = false;
    function loadIframeSource2() {
        if (token_holders_loaded == false) {
            token_holders_loaded = true;
            document.getElementById('tokeholdersiframe').src = '/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0xe94327d07fc17907b4db788e5adf2ed424addff6&s=11000000000000000000000000';
        }
    }

    var token_transactions_loaded = false;
    function loadIframeSource3() {
        if (token_transactions_loaded == false) {
            token_transactions_loaded = true;
            document.getElementById('tokentxnsiframe').src = '/token/generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=0xe94327d07fc17907b4db788e5adf2ed424addff6&a=&mode=';
        }
    }


</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the url? It'll be easier to solve your problem with the actual url.

Comment: One thing that may be happening is that the element with `id='maintable'` is present in the webpage before the execution of JS. So you're getting the original page source. Try using another element for `WebDriverWait` which is not present in the page source. Use an element which you can see by inspecting, but can't be found in the page source by searching it.

Comment: yeah... difficult to help without the link...